# Bug-free cloud note-taking software (alternative to Evernote)

Tags: osx, note-taking, cloud-service

I'm a premium user of Evernote for more than a year (MacBook Air running OS X 10.10 & Evernote 5.6.2 beta).

Last two updates inserted ​bugs on file attachment and context pasting process.

Upon inserting or pasting file or image inside a note it freezes the user interface from 10 to 60 seconds (yes, 60 seconds!).

Since I rely upon such tool for professional and personal life you can bet it's driving me crazy sometimes.

I've had support from their team but after three releases (1 stable & 2 beta) the problem remains.

What I do need:

- Full text searching inside PDF files and pasted images (PNG at most)
- Linking notes to one another
- Fast response

So I started to look for alternatives, such as DEVONthink Pro. I was not able to search inside PDF files nor images. Maybe the software has such feature. I mean it was not obvious to me, like in Evernote.

Despite of the fact I don't like the Microsoft UI style, I'm considering give OneNote a try, since I think OneNote should be a reloaded goold old Lotus Notes (the father of rich notes from Evernote possibly came).

Any recommendations shall be very welcome.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but do you really need to update? Can you revert to a functioning version and use some means (firewall...etc, not familiar with Mac) to prevent updates?